ESP32 with neopixel library causes TG1WDT_SYS_RESET bootloop
The neopixel library is causing a TG1WDT_SYS_RESET bootloop on a DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1 in Arduino IDE.
rst:0x8 (TG1WDT_SYS_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT) configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00 mode:DIO, clock div:1 load:0x3fff0030,len:1184 load:0x40078000,len:13160 load:0x40080400,len:3036 entry 0x400805e4
This is the error message that is shown. I've searched the internet for solutions but non really seem to work.
shown below is the neopixel 'simple' code example, that also triggers the issue. But I couldn't share my original code as it's a 1000+ lines
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PIN 6
#define NUMPIXELS 1
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRBW);
#define DELAYVAL 500

void setup() {
  pixels.begin();
}

void loop() {
  pixels.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMPIXELS; i++) {
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0, 150, 0));
    pixels.show();
    delay(DELAYVAL);
  }
}


I've tried rerolling ESP Core version, from; 3.0.8 -> 2.0.7 -> 2.0.4
and downgrading the neopixel library from;   1.12.3 -> 1.10.4
that didnt seem to work.
Downsizing the LED count to 1 strip with 1 led didn't work.
I also tried disabling the watchdog timer but that didn't help either.
I included; #include "esp_task_wdt.h"
and added; esp_task_wdt_deinit(); to the setup
and/or adding; esp_task_wdt_reset(); to the loop
but that didnt do anything.
I included; #include "soc/rtc_wdt.h"
and added; rtc_wdt_disable(); to the setup
but that didnt work either.
tossing some yield();'s in the mix didn't do much either

Add some serial output and a 1 second delay before calling any of the neopixel code. The way it stands you don’t output anything so we don’t know whether the program is corrupted or whether it’s a problem with the neopixel code.

Was an IO mismatch. Gpio 6 caused it to reboot.
Just realized it when I woke up this morning
